Spanning subgraph with prescribed even vertices of odd degree
In a paper by C. Thomassen, the author said the Lemma 1 is a "well-known" exercise and skipped the proof, while I have not seen this lemma before.
Lemma: If $A$ is an even vertex set in a connected graph $G$, then $G$ has a spanning subgraph $H$ such that every vertex in $A$ has odd $H$-degree, and all other vertices have even $H$-degree.
Terminology: $A$ is an even vertex set in $G$ means $|A|$ is even; the $H$-degree of a vertex $v$ is the degree of $v$ in graph $H$.

Induction on $|A|$.
When $|A| = 0$, let $H$ be the spanning empty subgraph of $G$, that is, $V(H) = V(G)$ and $E(H) = \emptyset$. Then every vertex has even $H$-degree.
Suppose the lemma is true for all even vertex sets of size less than $2k$.
Let $|A| = 2k$ and $u,v \in A$ be two distinct vertices of $A$.
By inductive assumption, there exists a spanning subgraph $H'$ such that every vertex of $A \setminus \{u,v\}$ has odd $H$-degree and every other vertex has even $H$-degree.
Since $G$ is connected, there exists a path $P$ from $u$ to $v$ in $G$.
Let $H$ be the spanning subgraph of $G$ such that $E(H) = E(H') \Delta E(P)$, the symmetric difference of $E(H')$ and $E(P)$.
Then, every vertex of $A$ has odd $H$-degree and every vertex not in $A$ has even degree.

There's a much more direct, though equivalent, way to phrase the proof (IE without using induction). Just take the symmetric difference of these $|A|/2$ paths (some details needed).

@CalvinLin In other words, take all edges that lie on an odd number of those paths.
